# Divs rendering properly only when inspect element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a project where I need to load a html page to another page. I have used jquery for that.But the problem is whenever the page is loaded the div elements are not positioned correctly(check the picture screenshot below). They are working once inspect element is clicked. I had checked many questions based on this wierd functioning but couldn't get through this error.Here is my code:
     HTML part:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <script  src="js/jquery1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>
      <div id="sidebar">
           <ul>
             <li id="ft-bar"><h3><a><span class="icon-signal"></span>Freshtime Context Bar</a></h3></li>
           </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="maincontent">
      </div>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#ft-bar').click(function(){   
               $('#maincontent').load('ftp-bar.html');     
         })     
    });
```

ftp-bar.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Product Life range slider</title>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />  
  <script  src="js/jquery1.js"></script>
  <script  src="js/colResizable-1.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){   

    //callback function
    var onSlide = function(e){
        var columns = $(e.currentTarget).find("td");
        var ranges = [], total = 0, i, s ="Ranges: ", w;
        for(i = 0; i<columns.length; i++){
            w = columns.eq(i).width()-10 - (i==0?1:0);
            ranges.push(w);
            total+=w;
        }        
        for(i=0; i<columns.length; i++){            
            ranges[i] = 100*ranges[i]/total;
            carriage = ranges[i]-w
            s+=" "+ Math.round(ranges[i]) + "%,";           
        }           
        s=s.slice(0,-1);            
        $("#text").html(s);
    }

    //colResize the table
   $("#product-life-slider").colResizable({
        liveDrag:true, 
        draggingClass:"", 
        onResize:onSlide,
        gripInnerHtml:"<div class='box1'>Grower <br> 2 Days</div>   <div class='label1'></div>", 
        minWidth:8
        });

}); 
  </script>

 </head>
 <body>
<div class="containerftp">  

        <table width="80%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="20%"><input type="text" class="ftp" name="Days to Useby" placeholder="Days to Useby" value=""></td>
        <td width="20%"><input type="text" class="ftp" name="Storage Temp" placeholder="Storage Temp" value=""></td>
        <td width="20%"><input type="text" class="ftp" name="Storage Time" placeholder="Storage Time" value=""></td>
        <td width="20%"><input type="range" class="ftp" value="30" min="0" max="100"/></td>
        <td width="20%"><input type="text" class="ftp" name="Average Temperature" placeholder="Average Temp" value=""></td>
      </tr>
    </table>    

    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>      

    <table id="product-life-slider" width="80%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" padding-left="2%">
        <tr>
            <td class="partner" width="2%"></td>
            <td class="partner" width="24%"></td>
            <td class="partner" width="6%"></td>
            <td class="partner" width="27%"></td>
            <td class="consumer" width="14%"></td>
            <td class="useby" width="27%"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>
```

CSS part:

```
.containerftp{margin:5% auto;text-align:left; position:relative;}

input[type=range].ftp:first-of-type {width: 120px;}
input.ftp {padding:10px;width:85%;border:1px solid #c5dbef;border-radius:5px; background:#e0effc;font-size:14px;}
input.ftp ::-webkit-input-placeholder {color: rgba(0,5,143,.5);text-transform: uppercase;}
input.ftp ::-moz-placeholder {color: rgba(0,5,143,.5);text-transform: uppercase;}
input.ftp :-moz-placeholder {color: rgba(0,5,143,.5);text-transform: uppercase;}  /* Older versions of Firefox */
input.ftp :-ms-input-placeholder { color: rgba(0,5,143,.5);text-transform: uppercase;}

#product-life-slider {border:1px solid #A6C9E2; border-radius:5px;}
#product-life-slider td{height:100px;border:none;}


.partner{background: rgba(154,255,87,1);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(154,255,87,1) 0%, rgba(68,201,59,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(154,255,87,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(68,201,59,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(154,255,87,1) 0%, rgba(68,201,59,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(154,255,87,1) 0%, rgba(68,201,59,1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(154,255,87,1) 0%, rgba(68,201,59,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(154,255,87,1) 0%, rgba(68,201,59,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#9aff57', endColorstr='#44c93b', GradientType=0 );   
border-right: 1px solid #000 !important;}

/* consumer */    
.consumer{background: rgba(255,238,87,1);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,238,87,1) 0%, rgba(255,176,66,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(255,238,87,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255,176,66,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,238,87,1) 0%, rgba(255,176,66,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,238,87,1) 0%, rgba(255,176,66,1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,238,87,1) 0%, rgba(255,176,66,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,238,87,1) 0%, rgba(255,176,66,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffee57', endColorstr='#ffb042', GradientType=0 );
border-right: 1px solid #000 !important;}

 /* UseBy */      
.useby{background: rgba(255,160,87,1);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,160,87,1) 0%, rgba(255,88,66,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(255,160,87,1)),    color-stop(100%, rgba(255,88,66,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,160,87,1) 0%, rgba(255,88,66,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,160,87,1) 0%, rgba(255,88,66,1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,160,87,1) 0%, rgba(255,88,66,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,160,87,1) 0%, rgba(255,88,66,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffa057', endColorstr='#ff5842', GradientType=0 );}

  /* column anchors */    
div.box1{   position: absolute;
        margin-top:-55px;
         margin-left:-36.8px; 
         width:70px;height:40px;
         background:#e0effc; 
         border-radius:5px; 
         border:1px solid #c5dbef; 
         font-size:13px; 
         padding:5px; 
         text-align:center;
          }
 div.label1 {position: absolute; 
        margin-left:-9px;
        width:0;height:0;
        border-left:13px solid transparent;
        border-right: 13px solid transparent;
        border-top: 13px solid #e0effc; 
        cursor:e-resize;}
```

The code is a bit messy but someone please help me in resolving this issue.
Thanks in advance.
   Here is the  image:[image]

Comment: What browser are you using ?

Comment: I am using google chrome Version 29.0.1547.65

Comment: Could you recreate it in a fiddle ?

Comment: There's quite a lot wrong with this - why are you loading jQuery three times (twice in the main HTML and once in ftp-bar.html) and why are you nesting a complete HTML document within another - you should be using an iFrame (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) for this or (better yet) only adding the div "containerftp" as a child of "maincontent". If you can't change ftp-bar.html it should be possible to select that div using jQuery and insert it into the main document.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue when I placed a 100% width 100% height div above the body whose opacity I varied to create a background effect. More than often the body's background never showed up unless I inspected the page that is.

The solution I found was to set the width and height of this div **and the body** programatically (force on document load and window resize).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#panel').height($(window).height());
    $('#panel').width($(window).width());
    $('body').height($(window).height());
    $('body').width($(window).width());
});
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#panel').height($(window).height());
    $('#panel').width($(window).width());
    $('body').height($(window).height());
    $('body').width($(window).width());
});
```

You can find an analogous solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is nothing weird about that, inspect element resizes your screen, so if your design is not static and responds to window size, you are going to get weird results. Solution would be either to make your design totally static, independent of size of browser window, or to fix the responsiveness of CSS :)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. Issue was the one of the element inside main DIV had height in %(percentage). Commenting the height resolved the issue for me.